# Prove that the lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ does not admit any two-dimensional Lie subalgebra.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Prove that the lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ does not admit any two-dimensional Lie subalgebra.

Consider the basis given by $e_1=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0}, e_2=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0}$ and $e_3=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0}$ for $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Suppose that $\mathfrak g$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, with basis $$\{v=v^1e_1+v^2e_2+v^3e_3, u=u^1e_1+u^2e_2+u^3e_3\}.$$

Now I think that the idea is to show that the Lie bracket is not closed i.e. $[v,u] \notin \mathfrak g$?

Computing I got that $$[v,u]=(v^2u^3-v^3u^2)e_1+(v^3u^1-v^1u^3)e_2+(v^1u^2-v^2u^1)e_3$$ but I'm not sure why this isn't in $\mathfrak g$?

Comment: Do the coefficients of $[v,u]$ remind you of something you learned at the beginning of your multivariable calculus class?

Comment: Oh is it the cross product in disguise here? @TedShifrin

Comment: Indeed!! That explains the determinant @JohnHughes wrote in his answer.

Comment: Well...sort of. I just meant that if the coefficients of vectors u, v, w are put in a matrix and the det is 0, then u, v, and w are linearly dependent (indeed, if and only if). The "w" vector didn't *have* to be the cross-product for that general idea to work. (I know Ted knows this, but wanted to be sure Nathaniel got it as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint, but deliberately not a complete answer:**

Suppose that it *were* in $g$. Then it would be a linear combination of the first two (nonzero) elements, right? So what would be the determinant of
$$
\pmatrix{v^1 & v^2 & v^3 \\
u^1 & u^2 & u^3 \\
v^2u^3-v^3u^2&v^3u^1-v^1u^3&v^1u^2-v^2u^1}?
$$

And what would that tell you about the coefficient vectors $u$ and $v$?

Comment: What do you mean by first two nonzero elements? Like $[v,u] = \alpha v + \beta u$? @john-hughes

Comment: By that phrase, I meant "u and v", yes. So this lie bracket would be a linear combination of $u$ and $b$. And that would tell you something about the determinant of the matrix I wrote.